# Running flask as package in production

Tags: python, heroku, flask, pip

I am trying to deploy my flask app. Usually I would have an `app.py` and put all code in it.

```
app.py
templates/
|
|--index.html
```

for my really small projects. But then I have a slightly larger app and follow [the larger app guide by flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/).
So I have this:

```
setup.py
app/
    __init__.py
    views.py
    models.py
    forms.py
    templates/
    | ---index.html
```

I now have all my routes and views in `views.py` and *running* the app in `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import app.views # Name in setup.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

(This is just an example)
So now I follow the guide by running it with `pip install -e .` and running with:
`>set FLASK_APP=app(name I set in setup.py)` `flask run` and it works. Except I do not know how to run it with one command. Since there is no *one file to run* I can not use gunicorn or anything like that. I am not sure how to go about executing this app. How would I run `pip install .` on the cloud server heroku?
My problem is because I have to import the `app` from `__init__.py` and views using import *blog*.[insert import] *(models, views etc.)* Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**: I do not want to use blueprints though. That might be *too* much. My app is medium, not small but not large either

Comment: Did you try using a heroku `Procfile` as detailed here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You absolutely can use Gunicorn to run this project. Gunicorn is not limited to a single file, it imports Python modules just the same as `flask run` can. Gunicorn just needs to know the module to import, an the WSGI object to call within that module.

When you use `FLASK_APP`, all that `flask run` does is look for `module.app`, `module.application` or instances of the `Flask()` class. It also supports a `create_app()` or `make_app()` app factory, but you are not using such a factory.

Gunicorn won't search, if you only give it a module, it'll expect the name `application` to be the WSGI callable. In your case, you are using `app` so all you have to do is explicitly tell it what name to use:

```
gunicorn app:app
```

The part before the `:` is the module to import (`app` in your case), the part after the colon is the callable object (also named `app` in your module).

If you have set `FLASK_APP` as a [Heroku config var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) and want to re-use that, you can reference that on the command line for `gunicorn`:

```
gunicorn $FLASK_APP:app
```

Answer (score -1):

As for heroku, it can handle `requirement.txt` or `setup.py`

c.f. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#local-file-backed-distributions

> If your Python application contains a setup.py file but excludes a requirements.txt file, python setup.py develop will be used to install your package and resolve your dependencies.
>
> If you already have a requirements file, but would like to utilize this feature, you can add the following to your requirements file:
>
> `-e .`

And about run command, i think you cat put Procfile like

```
web: FLASK_APP=app flask run
```

or

```
web: FLASK_APP=app python -m flask run
```